# add List to session and iterate on it

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have done a little web app I'm using thymeleaf and jsp for frontend, now I need to use 2 object, a list and a simple object, in the controller I use this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/attivita")
public String newCentro(@Valid @ModelAttribute("attivita") Attivita attivita,
                        Model model, BindingResult br, HttpSession session) {
    this.validator.validate(attivita, br);
    if (br.hasErrors()) {
        return "attivitaForm/formAttivita";
    } else if (this.service.alreadyExists(attivita)) {
        model.addAttribute("exists", "Questa attività già esiste");
        return "attivitaForm/formAttivita";
    }
    session.setAttribute("attivita", attivita);
    // session.setAttribute("centri", this.centroService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("centri", this.centroService.findAll());
    return "attivitaForm/addCentro2Attivita";
}
```

and in the page html I use this:

```
<div th:each="centro : ${centri}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-left">
            <a th:href="@{'/confermaAttivita' + '/' + ${centro.id} }">
                <span th:text="${centro.nome}" style="text-decoration: underline;"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><span th:text="${centro.indirizzo}"></span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><span th:text="${centro.email}"></span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><span th:text="${centro.capienzamax}"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and up to here it work well, I see the list of center, but from now the list is lose, because I go to another page of check and after that page I return this:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [capienzamax]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement.
```

and in STS I see this logs:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [capienzamax]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "capienzamax" violates not-null constraint
  Dettaglio: Failing row contains (12, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).
```

I think is because the object select from the list is lose, but I see the id is memorized

Comment: try setting the initial data set to session.

Comment: @SupunDharmarathne, like the commented row? because i have done, but the html don't display it without changes, and i don't now how to display it, thanks

Comment: are you doing any other db operation while traversing between these two pages?

Comment: It would be better if you share your full implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As per the Error look at your Database's table.You have "null" value somewhere in "capienzamax" column.

Comment: yes, but i have retrive the object centro from the database with the findById(id), it haven't that data null

Comment: As per the error your coulmn **capienzamax** is Set to **not-null** and you're trying to insert a  **null** value in it,
 thats the reason you're getting this error.
If you're able to get the value in your thyemleaf of **${centro.capienzamax}**  but not after submitting you're getting this error means you're not getting your **capienzamax** object  on your controller.

Comment: When you are trying with findAll(), it may contain some records with null values.
Try doing something like this.

 model.addAttribute("centri",this.centroService.findById(id));

Comment: @Sumityes, that's the problem, but why, so  the object is retrive from the db, and if it is on the DB the field exists, and in the page where i can select the center i see the data are okey:
 <div class="col-xs-3"><span th:text ="${centro.capienzamax}"></span></div>
                       </div>
this is display

Comment: @SupunDharmarathne i use this find all to display all center, and if i click on one i save it and get the id i use to retrive it:

@RequestMapping("/confermaAttivita/{id}")
 public String conferma(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model, HttpSession session) {
  Centro c = this.centroService.findById(id);
  model.addAttribute("centro",c);
  return "attivitaForm/paginaConfermaAttivita";
 }

Comment: @CristianMonti then in that case make sure you're catching your **capienzamax** object in proper setter & getter methods on the controller after clicking submit button.

Comment: @CristianMonti just check whether you are saving the center data with all the valid fields (not null)

Comment: @SupunDharmarathne i haven't solve it, but i need more help, because i have other page, and i don't know where the error is

Comment: @CristianMonti 
show your controller code where you're getting ** capienzamax** object , let's see if I could do anything to help you out.

Comment: @CristianMonti It would be better if you can share full implementation